# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache..ctor'

Tags: .net, azure, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have a new project with in .net6 with Azure Function v4 as well as aspnet core mvc api sharing a project library. I'm also using EF Core 6.0.19 with dependency injection (injecting a dbcontext factory).

In my Azure Function, when accessing the DbContext I get the following error, I cannot understand why.

I've tried EF Core 6.0.18 and 6.0.0, but I still get the same error.

**Error**

```
Error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheOptions>)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_10(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at MyProject.Data.Repositories.Mobile.MyRepository.Find(Guid installationID) in C:\Users\SamSneed\source\repos\MyProject_api.Sam.Sneed\MyProject.Data\Repositories\Mobile\MyRepository.cs:line 29
```

This is the **MyRepository.cs** class where the error occurs.

```
        private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> _options;

        public MyRepository(
            IRepositoryDependencyProvider repositoryDependencyProvider,
            DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
            : base(repositoryDependencyProvider)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        public MobileInstallation Find(Guid installationID)
        {
            using var context = new MyDbContext(_options, _currentUser, _dbConnectionService);
            var userID = CurrentUser.GetUserID();
            // Fails on the next line
            return context.MobileInstallations.Where(r => r.InstallationID == installationID && r.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault(); 
        }
```

This is the DI in my shared startup code between the function and the api:

```
            services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>((options) => {
                options.UseSqlServer(r => r.UseNetTopologySuite());
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

**MyDbContext.cs** (gets the user's connection string from the multitenant shard data)

```
        private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _principal;
        private readonly int? _shardID;
        private readonly IDbConnectionService _dbConnectionService;

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IPrincipal principal, IDbConnectionService dbConnectionService, int? shardID = null) : base(options)
        {
            _shardID = shardID;
            _principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)principal;
            _dbConnectionService = dbConnectionService;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            int? shardID = _shardID ?? _principal.GetShardID();
            if (shardID.HasValue)
            {
                optionsBuilder
                    .UseSqlServer(_dbConnectionService.SqlConnection(shardID.Value), (x) => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
                    ;
            }
        }
```

**Function.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.30.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.19" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="6.0.19" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

MVC.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCoreMigrationShims.NewtonsoftJson.NetFrameworkCompatibility" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

SharedStartup.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake" Version="12.14.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you please share the .csproj  file?

Comment: @GuruStron I have added the csproj for the function

Comment: Try explicitly installing `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` 6.0.1.

Comment: But in general everything looks ok. Was not able to repro.

Comment: Do you. know that EF Core. 7 is targeted to .NET 6? Maybe better to start new project with latest EF version?

Comment: Does your `aspnet core mvc api` is in the same Solution?Please provide the `.csproj` for this as well.

Comment: Please share your Application Folder Structure.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes I know that .ef core 7 is available but ef core 7 doesn’t play nicely with azure functions - I’ve already tried.

Comment: @Harshitha I added the MVC.csproj

Comment: @Harshitha the application is quite large. I have tried to keep it slim here so far for ease of understanding.

Comment: NP..will try to repro from my end and let you know.

Comment: Updating the question with the csproj from my common project that the function and the api share. This project provides dependency injection packages that were referencing 7.0.0 versions instead of 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 7.0.0 packages in the SharedStartup.csproj to be for .net6.

Change

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
```

to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
```